# Why don't java enums allow accessing item-specific fields/methods

Tags: java, enums

You are allowed to have enum fields/methods that are specific to each item like this in java

```
enum E {
    A {
        public int a = 3;
    },
    B {
        public void x() {}
    };
}
```

But you are not allowed to do this:

```
int x = E.A.a; // cannot resolve symbol 'a'
E.B.x() // cannot resolve method 'x'
```

Why is this not allowed?

Comment: I am suspecting perhaps each item is an anonymous class that is typed only as `E`. Still, item-specific fields it would be a mildly useful thing to be able to do

Comment: Your suspect is 100% correct, and Java just doesn't allow it.

Comment: You have item specific fields and methods. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html the planets example.

Comment: I may want a different number of variables with a different number of names though.

Comment: Yeah at that point, though, is what you want really an enum?